# Javascript separate window for games

Tags: javascript

I'm new to JavaScript and want to try and make a word guessing game in a new window like they do at http://www.lutanho.net/stroke/online.html. I don't get how it opens up in its own separate window? I want to write it in a .js file and attach it to an index.html file, so when i click on the h ref it opens that window. 
heres my code:

```
<head>
<title>Caelan Bacon</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
        <script type="text/javascript" src="rockPaperScissors.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="delayedAlert.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="RockSpock.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="realTime.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="caelansGame.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

<div class="dropdown">
 <button class="dropbtn">JavaScript</button>
<div class="dropdown-content">
    <a href="#" onclick="delayedAlert()">Delayed Alert</a>
    <a href="#" onclick="rockPaperScissors()">rock, paper, scissors</a>
    <a href="#" onclick="RockSpock()">Rock Spock</a>
    <a href="#" onclick="realTime()">Real Time</a>
    <a href="#" onclick="window.open('caelansGame.js')">New Window</a>
</div>
```

and then in my .js file…

```
 var newWindow = window.open('','preview','width=600,height=500');

function setup {
    prompt ="Que pasa?"
    };
```

caelansGame.js is the one I want to open a new window where i can have alerts within that window

Comment: What have you done so far? Can you show us?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is exactly how you can do it :

**BY USING :**

```
window.open(url, windowName, "height=200,width=200");
```

**SAMPLE WORKING CODE :**

```
<button id="check">Open Window</button> 

<script type="text/javascript">
var myElement = document.getElementById("check");
myElement.onclick = function () {
window.open("http://www.google.com/", "MyWindow", "height=200,width=200");
};
</script>
```

**LIVE DEMO :** https://jsfiddle.net/so8xeg43/

**Note :** For checking I may suggest to disable your Popup Blockers Extensions like Ads Blocker etc in your Browser before visiting the JSFiddle Link or testing code at your own side..!

**TESTING RESULTS :**

- Opens a new Window in Chrome (Even while keeping Ads Blocker Turned ON)
- Opens a new Window in Microsoft Edge
- Opens a new Tab in Firefox

Answer (score 1):

You may try:

```
 window.open("http://yourUrl", "_blank", "width=600,height=500")
```

Or you can use this script:

```
<button onclick="myFunction()">Try it</button>

    <script>
    function myFunction() {
        window.open("http://yourUrl");  //Opens in separate window
    }
    </script>
```

Comment: I'm not trying to open a new tab (safari), I'm trying to open up a new window.

Comment: Nope..it doesn't open a new window it opens a new tab..!

Comment: @UmairShahYousafzai,  Safari and Chrome have these strict popup blockers built in and turned on by default, it's not that other browsers don't have them -- it's just that for other browsers they are either add-ons or not automatically turned on at installation time.